# f-strings formatter including for-loop or if conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

How can I insert `for` loops or `if` expressions inside an **f-string**?

I thought initially of doing something like this for `if` expressions:

```
f'{a:{"s" if CONDITION else "??"}}'
```

What I would like to do though is something like:

**Example 1**

```
f'{key: value\n for key, value in dict.items()}'
```

**result:**

*if dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}*

```
a: 1 
b: 2
```

or **Example 2**

```
c = 'hello'
f'{c} {name if name else "unknown"}'
```

**result:**

*if name exists, e.g. name = 'Mike'*

```
hello Mike
```

*otherwise*

```
hello unknown
```

Can this be done and if yes how?

Comment: What is the expected result of the second example?

Comment: You can't put a *statement* in an `f` string, only an expression. `... if ... else ...` is not an `if` statement; it's a conditional expression.

Comment: Pleave en example of the expecte output for each

Comment: The second one will raise a `NameError` if `name` isn't actually set, not be treated as a false value.

Comment: The first one isn't an expression at all; it's a fragment of a dict comprehension.

Comment: For first one you can put f-string inside dict comprehension, like `{f'{key, value}' for key, value in dict.items()}`

Comment: For the record, `f'{ {key: value for key, value in dict.items()} }'` works just fine, you just need separate braces for the `dict` comprehension.

Comment: Question edited to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both ternaries ("`if` expressions") and comprehensions ("`for` expressions") are allowed inside f-strings. However, they must be part of expressions that evaluate to strings. For example, `key: value` is a dict pair, and `f"{key}: {value}"` is required to produce a string.

```
>>> dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> newline = "\n"  # \escapes are not allowed inside f-strings
>>> print(f'{newline.join(f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in dct.items())}')
a: 1
b: 2
```

Note that if the entire f-string is a single format expression, it is simpler to just evaluate the expression directly.

```
>>> print("\n".join(f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in dct.items())))
a: 1
b: 2
```

Expressions inside format strings still follow their regular semantics. For example, a ternary may test whether an *existing* name is true. It will fail if the name is not defined.

```
>>> c, name = "Hello", ""
>>> f'{c} {name if name else "unknown"}'
'Hello unknown'
>>> del name
>>> f'{c} {name if name else "unknown"}'
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Comment: Not a big deal, but you can use `os.linesep` instead of `newline`. `import os` then `print(f'{os.linesep.join(f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in dct.items())}')`