# Is there any way to fill empty string into {} if the variable of {} does not exist?

Tags: python, string

```
# Evaluation result.
train_eval_results = model.evaluate(x_train, [y_train, x_train])
val_eval_results = model.evaluate(x_val, [y_val, x_val])
batch_size = 2
tc = TimeChecker()

### model is from Keras package.
### val_eval_results is a list of 5 float numbers.

content = f"""
train_evaluation_result = {train_eval_results[4]:.4f}
val_evaluation_result = {val_eval_results[4]:.4f}
elapsed_time = {tc.show_elapsed_time()} 
batch_size = {batch_size}
"""

### # show_elapsed_time() return a string.
```

I want to make a readme file which includes the above content.
But sometimes part of the variables in {} do not exist. **In that situation, i want to fill empty string or "not defined" thing into {}.**

Could you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by `do not exist` ? Are they None ? Just put the default value at the moment you read the value, it'd be easier

Comment: Maybe print `train` and `eval` when they are being calculated? (rather than in a sinlgle print statement)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [f-strings formatter including for-loop or if conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956496/f-strings-formatter-including-for-loop-or-if-conditions)

Comment: @azro For example sometimes there is no validation set so in that situation val_eval_results is not defined.

Comment: Could share the code of the assignment of one variable ? Because if not defined at all you just can’t use the variable

Answer (score 5):

I Believe you can use the inline conditional:

```
f"batch_size = {batch_size if batch_size else ''}"
```